# Open my Java application on local website (HTML)

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I've finished my project in Eclipse en build the Java.jar file, it runs fine when i click it on my browser but now i want it on a local website so for examle c:/user..... so it will run in the browser but how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just simply run a java application with a web browser only from your hard drive...Unless it is an applet like the previous owner said.
In general you will need to setup some kind of application server (tomcat, jboss,...)

Answer (score 0):

> is it an application or an applet??.

Unless the jar file also contains an applet class, there's no way to get it to work in a browser as is.

---

Check this out this [Applet](http://www.acme.com/resources/classes/Acme/ApplicationApplet.java)  Class.

You also need
[TomCat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-55.cgi) or [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/public/downloadsindex.html)

Comment: and as @user935439 you need a local or remote server

Comment: i haven't any idea how to do this